# How send an ActionResult from a ClassLibrary project to another project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, actionresult

I moved the Identity classes and the AccountController into a new ClassLibrary and everything is fine, except for 2 things. The first thing I noticed is that I am getting this warning, when calling the Register Method
[image: Warning Message]

here is the code where the warning is showing, its empty right now because I just wanted to make sure that I could reach the Register method and it does reach the Register method in the AccountController class.

```
public void CreateNewAdministrator(NewAdministrator administrator)
    {
        #region Initialization

        RegisterViewModel rvm = new RegisterViewModel();

        #endregion

        AccountController.Register(rvm);
    }
```

The second issue I am going to encounter is in the Register Method itself, here is the Register method

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, AccountNumber = model.AccountNumber };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Where I am foreseeing the issue is the

> return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

I need this to return back to the view in the MainProject area, another is thing is if I can get it to call the view from where its being called, I wouldn't want it to cause a refresh of the view. I am calling this method using JQuery Ajax so the page doesn't refresh when a new record is added.

I know that I am going to encounter yet another issue with this, but that can be another question.

Answer (score 0):

As the warning says, You will need to `await` your `AccountController.Register(rvm);`.

Do this so that the current method does not continue executing before the `Register` method is complete, This may also fix your second issue as that may be caused by this problem.

Also please provide full plaintext of all warnings, errors and/or exceptions that you get.